# utf8 format in xml

Tags: xml, unicode, utf-8

i want to know how to store this è (this type of symbols) in xml file

if i store this symbol in xml file..

the file shows this symbol like �

i was inserted in front of xml  file is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

but that doest not shows correct

thanks and advance

Comment: Which editor are you using to view the text?

Answer (score 3):

Did you remember your XML declaration?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<element>egalité</element>
```

You also need to ensure that the document is *actually* stored as UTF-8; check the encoding settings of the text editor used to make it for this.

Comment: He did. He just didn't format the code in his question so that the xml declaration disappeared. This problem is likely caused by saving the file using the wrong encoding.

Comment: @BalusC: Well, I answered before you edited his reply to make it pop. ;) Still a useful part of the answer, I feel. :P

Answer (score 2):

You have a character encoding problem. The encoding used to save the file does not match the one being used to read the file. Ideally, both should use an encoding like UTF-8. Ensure you are writing and reading the file correctly in this regard. You would have to show more about what you are doing to get a more specific reply.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today...in my case the file wasn't saved as UTF-8...

try e.g. notepad++ (maybe windows editor supports this also) and change the encoding to utf8.
after this replace the silly symbol by your é again.

this should help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you save xml file encodind in UTF-8 (in Notepad use save as and choose UTF-8 encoding) and start your xml file with the line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

it will work. To verify your results just open xml file in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem while you insert

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

inside of your XML Document, Then you don't save your xml as a UTF-8 document. to do this.

Copy all of you XML contentin memory, open  'notepad' and Paste the content in 'notepad'. then Save your document as a Unicode document (from save dialog box (file type))